# which is the best way to order by count from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm wondering about these queries and I got a work that want to list all users in table `user` and count for their `post` `photo` and `video`. and can choose to view in sort by these count limit by `ASC` or `DESC`.
I've tried them both but see that sub-query is fast than join. i want to know the different between these queries. Why sometimes join is slower that a sub-query. is join best for only two tables? Is this both best for my work? or you can suggest another better solution.

**SUB-QUERY**

```
select
          user.*,
          (select count(*) from post where post.userid = user.id) postCount,
          (select count(*) from photo where photo.userid = user.id) photoCount,
          (select count(*) from video where video.userid = user.id) videoCount
        from user order by postCOunt desc limit $starrow 20
```

**JOIN**

```
SELECT u.id, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS postCount,
        COUNT(DISTINCT ph.id) AS photoCount,
        COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS videoCount
    FROM user u
        LEFT JOIN post p
            ON p.userid = u.id
        LEFT JOIN photo ph
            ON ph.userid = u.id
        LEFT JOIN video v
            ON v.userid = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id
    ORDER BY postCount LIMIT $startrow 20
```

Example in HTML page that order by `postCount DESC` and have paging.

```
userid         postCount      photoCount    videCount
1              34             5             4
2              30             12            2
3              21             5             6
4              15             8             4
5              12             15            9
6              8              3             10
```

..              ..             ..            ..

Comment: why not `order by userid` since that's looks like a unique column.

Comment: I want to create ranking page and it can apply to another work too. such as, listing the first 100 users that have most post, or list users from the highest to lowest score.

Comment: Could you update your post with the result of `EXPLAIN xxx` where you replace xxx first with the first and then with the second query? `EXPLAIN` explains how MySQL processes a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way with `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT u.id, postCount, photoCount, videoCount
  FROM user u LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) postCount
      FROM post
     GROUP BY userid
  ) p ON p.userid = u.id LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) photoCount
      FROM photo
     GROUP BY userid
  ) ph ON ph.userid = u.id LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) videoCount
      FROM video
     GROUP BY userid
  ) v ON v.userid = u.id
 ORDER BY postCount 
 LIMIT $startrow, 20
```